# How to deal 'void cpr::Session::SetOption(const cpr::Url &)': cannot convert argument

Tags: http, post, visual-studio-2019, c++20

I would like to have a function that does this (Async POST with callback):

```cpp
void skip_to_next_action::operator()(const uint64_t &msg_id)
    {
        auto callback = [&](cpr::Response response)
        {
            if (m_handle_error_callback)
                m_handle_error_callback(msg_id, response);
        };

        cpr::PostAsync(cpr::Url(endpoints::player_next),
                       cpr::Bearer(get_oauth_token()),
                       cpr::Header{{s_content_type, s_application_json}},
                       callback);
    }
```

And when I try to compile it, I get:

```
error C2664: 'void cpr::Session::SetOption(const cpr::Url &)': cannot convert argument 1 from '_Ty' to 'const cpr::Url &'

message : Reason: cannot convert from '_Ty' to 'const cpr::Url'
with
[
    _Ty=spotify::skip_to_next_action::()::<lambda_1>
]

message : No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called

message : see declaration of 'cpr::Session::SetOption'

message : see reference to function template instantiation 'void cpr::priv::set_option_internal<true,_Ty>(cpr::Session &,CurrentType &&)' being compiled
with
[
    _Ty=spotify::skip_to_next_action::()::<lambda_1>,
    CurrentType=spotify::skip_to_next_action::()::<lambda_1>
]

message : see reference to function template instantiation 'cpr::Response cpr::Post<cpr::Url,cpr::Bearer,std::map<std::string,std::string,cpr::CaseInsensitiveCompare,std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string,std::string>>>,spotify::skip_to_next_action::()::<lambda_1>>(cpr::Url &&,cpr::Bearer &&,std::map<std::string,std::string,cpr::CaseInsensitiveCompare,std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string,std::string>>> &&,spotify::skip_to_next_action::()::<lambda_1> &&)' being compiled

message : see reference to function template instantiation 'cpr::AsyncResponse cpr::PostAsync<cpr::Url,cpr::Bearer,cpr::Header,spotify::skip_to_next_action::()::<lambda_1>>(cpr::Url,cpr::Bearer,cpr::Header,spotify::skip_to_next_action::()::<lambda_1>)' being compiled
```

According to the docs everything should be fine. What I did wrong?

I tried to find similar problem in google, but it seems to be pretty rare problem.
To deal with this I already tried adding Body{} and preconverting Url. Nothing helps. Something is wrong with the way I'm passing the callback.

I also tried to add return cpr::Url("") in callback. It also does not help.

I expect to have a non-blocking async POST request with error handling in callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need callbacks it's needed to use "[method]Callback(...)" functions and callback **must be first param** of this type of functions.

There was no such points in cpr docs. I've figured this out, while was reviewing cpr test cases on github.